# Puppet Server and Client working Good but still manifest file doesn't get executed

Tags: amazon-ec2, certificate, manifest, puppet

I am currently working on puppet using Amazon Fedora EC2 instances. Both Puppet Server and Client are working fine. I am able to create certificate from client and server is able to sign that but still whatever code I have written in manifest files doesn’t get executed.

Below mentioned is my code in Site.pp file :

```
class test_class {
    file { “/tmp/testfile”:
        ensure => present,
        mode => 644,
        owner => root,
        group => root
    }
}

node puppetclient {
   include test_class
}
```

Here, puppetclient is the hostname of client. But still after signing certificate /tmp/testfile doesn’t get created.

DNS is also working perfectly fine. I can ping puppetserver(named as puppet) from puppet client.

Can you please tell me what must be the possible mistake ??

Comment: Does it work if you do `node default { include test_client }`? Also, if you run the puppet master in debug mode `--debug` option what does the master think the client's hostname is?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a typo in the question, but the default catalog file is 'site.pp', not 'Site.pp', so try it with 'site.pp' instead.